# SQL Group By Multiple Columns Having More Than One Unique Value for Grouping Column

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to group by two columns where the first grouping column has more than one unique value for the second grouping column.  Below is a sample table with sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [UnitOfMeasure] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
) ON [PRimary]
) ON [PRimary];

INSERT INTO [MyTable] (Type, UnitOfMeasure)
VALUES ('height', 'cm')
,   ('distance', 'km')
,   ('weight', 'kg')
,   ('Glucose', 'mg/dL')
,   ('weight', 'kg')
,   ('Duration', 'hours')
,   ('Glucose', 'mg/dL')
,   ('Glucose', 'mg/dL')
,   ('height', 'cm')
,   ('Allergy', 'kUnits/L')
,   ('Volume', 'mL')
,   ('height', 'inch')
,   ('height', 'cm')
,   ('Chloride', 'mmol/L')
,   ('Volume', 'cup')
,   ('distance', 'km')
,   ('Volume', 'cup')
,   ('Duration', 'hours')
,   ('Chloride', 'mmol/L')
,   ('Duration', 'minutes');
```

The desired out put is as follows.

```
Type        UnitOfMeasure
Duration    hours
Duration    minutes
height      cm
height      inch
Volume      cup
Volume      mL
```

This output includes Duration because it has two unit of measures.  However, it does not include weight, nor Chloride, due to it having only a single unit of measure.

Comment: Seems odd that you have duplicate rows; have you considered fixing that?

Comment: To simplify the question, I did not include other columns, which, to your point, has the appearance of duplication.  The goal of the query is to identify types that has conflicting units of measure, like a type that has a unit of measure of cm and mL.  the table I am working with has millions of rows with with more than 10,000 types.  Just need to limit the number of types to check.  The query provided resulted in reducing the number of types to just over 700.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to get a `DISTINCT` `COUNT`, and then use an `EXISTS` with a further `DISTINCT`. I expect this to be a little expensive though, and ideally you probably want to address those duplicate rows you have.

```sql
WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT [Type],
           COUNT(DISTINCT UnitOfMeasure) AS DistinctMeasures
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    GROUP BY [Type])
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Type],
       UnitOfMeasure
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Counts C
              WHERE C.[Type] = MT.[Type]
                AND C.DistinctMeasures > 1);
```

Comment: Thank you!  A lot simpler than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.[Type], t.[UnitOfMeasure]
FROM [MyTable] t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [MyTable]
  WHERE [Type] = t.[Type] AND [UnitOfMeasure] <> t.[UnitOfMeasure]
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07c771f04914a15e3eeac205ed87a668).
Results:

```
> Type     | UnitOfMeasure
> :------- | :------------
> Duration | hours        
> Duration | minutes      
> height   | cm           
> height   | inch         
> Volume   | cup          
> Volume   | mL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions only. Just compare the min and max unit per type: if they differ, then you know you have at least two distinct values, and you can retain the corresponding rows:

```
select distinct type, unitofmeasure
from (
    select t.*,
        min(unitofmeasure) over(partition by type) min_unit,
        max(unitofmeasure) over(partition by type) max_unit
    from mytable t
) t
where min_unit <> max_unit
```